# Use TFS Changeset in Version Number

Tags: tfs, build, versioning, changeset

I have seen 'tf changeset /latest /i' referenced as an answer in getting the latest changeset version number to use in the msbuild version number but can't find any further information on where that gets placed?  I am using VS2010 and TFS2010 and am attempting to use changeset instead of version number.

Any help?

Comment: Do you do your builds with Team Build or just VS 2010 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MSBuild have a look at my [blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/07/versioning-builds-with-tfs-and-msbuild.html) on how to do it (TFS2008 but applicable to 2010).

If you are using workflows then you want [this blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-versioning-builds-with-tfs-2010.html) instead.

Hope that helps :-)